# How to work on the filter in the elasticsearch template?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-template

I have similar kind of data set to work on with Elasticsearch.

```
  {
    "id" :1,
    "title" : "Toy Story 1",
    "year" : 1995 ,
    "category" : "Adventure"
    },
    {
    "id" :2,
    "title" : "Jumanji",
    "year" : 1995,
    "category" : "Adventure"
    },
    {
    "id" :3,
    "title" : "Grumpier Old Men",
    "year" : 1996,
    "category" : "Comedy"
    },
    {
    "id" :4,
    "title" : "Toy Story 2",
    "year" : 1996,
    "category" : "Action"
    },
    {
    "id" :5,
    "title" : "Toy Story 3"
    "year" : 1997
    "category" : "Comedy"
    },
    {
    "id" :6,
    "title" : "Toy Story 4"
    "year" : 2019
    "category" : "Comedy"
    }
```

Here is the mapping for my index.

```
{
    "movies": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "category": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "year": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the search-template for retrieving the data.
I have created a template and querying the data by passing the id of the template.

You can refer the below link for the same.
[Search-template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html)

I am using postman for creating the template and querying the data using the template.

I created the template as below :

POST _scripts/test

```
{
    "script": {
        "lang": "mustache",
        "source": {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "title": "{{query_string}}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

POST _search/template

```
{
    "id": "test", 
    "params": {
        "query_string": "toy"
    }
}
```

This is working fine. I am getting the result as expected.

Now I am stuck with the filtering option in the template.

I want to filter on the category. I want add the category in the template and pass the values as `["Comedy", "Adventure"]`

How can we add the filters in the template and pass the array values to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way. First modify your script template like this:

```
POST _scripts/test
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": """
      {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "title": "{{query_string}}"
                }
              }
            ],
            "filter": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "category.keyword": {{#toJson}}categories{{/toJson}}
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    """
  }
}
```

Note that the above can only be executed inside Kibana Dev Tools (because of the triple quotes (`"""`).

If you're executing this somewhere else, you need to JSON-encode the query first:

```
POST _scripts/test
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": "{\n      \"query\": {\n        \"bool\": {\n          \"must\": [\n            {\n              \"match\": {\n                \"title\": \"{{query_string}}\"\n              }\n            }\n          ],\n          \"filter\": [\n            {\n              \"terms\": {\n                \"category.keyword\": {{#toJson}}categories{{\/toJson}}\n              }\n            }\n          ]\n        }\n      }\n    }"
  }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
POST _search/template
{
  "id": "test",
  "params": {
    "query_string": "toy",
    "categories": [
      "Comedy",
      "Adventure"
    ]
  }
}
```

It will yield this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "toy"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "category": [
              "Comedy",
              "Adventure"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ...I will try this and let you know...

Comment: I am getting an error while creating the template as "reason": "Unexpected character ('\"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@3c919a91; line: 4, column: 18]"

Comment: Which version of ES do you have?

Comment: I am using elasticsearch-7.2.1

Comment: Can you try again without the 3 double quotes `"""`?

Comment: yes...I tried with """....I copied your script as it is and pasted in postman and tried...It gives the same error

Comment: I said without, not with :-) `"""`only work in Kibana but not Postman

Comment: oops...I miss read it..Yes tried without """...its gives..."type": "json_parse_exception",
                "reason": "Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@7a2a73cb; line: 17, column: 33]"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213304/discussion-between-abhijit-bashetti-and-val).

Comment: The script executed successfully...But not able to get result after query execution...

Comment: I think I know why. Can you update your question with the mapping of your index?

Comment: Updated the question with mapping of my index.

Comment: Ok, updated my answer. You need to recreate the search template and then it should work

Comment: Which programming language are you using? I used [this](https://fr.functions-online.com/json_encode.html) just for the purpose of encoding it.

Comment: python...But I am writing the scripts/templates using the postman and saving it on elasticsearch

Comment: Then use a service similar to the one I showed, there are plenty online